# What skills don't reset Sharpshooter?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I know that Vault (Trail of Cinders) does not reset Sharpshooter, so after a while it always crits.
Are there other skills that don't reset Sharpshooter?

Comment: that's probably going to be fixed in the next patch as well.  When you deal damage that causes a crit, it should always reset sharpshooter

Comment: It's pretty much everything that deals damage (I think turrets also reset it). Like yx. said, it might be fixed next patch.

Comment: I understand it may be fixed in the next patch. I just ask what works in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in 1.04 the bat and sentry do not reset the sharpshooter bonus but do benefit from it.
I think dots like jagged spikes and trial of cinders were hotfixed not to make use of the sharpshooter bonus.
In 1.05 these mechanics will change: pets and sentries will not be able to crit anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

Caltrops#Jagged Spikes certainly does not reset Sharpshooter, and certainly does benefit from it.  This is the primary killing skill my DH uses, and I've re-tested it with every patch.  It still works.