# How does Trail of Cinders work (both 1.04 and 1.05)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

In 1.04, [Trail of Cinders](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault) does 1500% over 3 seconds.  Some say that this does not reset SharpShooter. [What Skills don't reset Sharpshooter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83247/what-skills-dont-reset-sharpshooter)

So when calculating the 1500% does it just take your Weapon Damage?
Does that include your Dex modifiers?
Can Trail of Cinders do Crits?

Now with 1.05 Trail of Cinders will only do 300% but stackable.  Does anyone know if the any of the above change also (Weapon Damage vs DPS, Crit Chance)?

Ps- If someone wants to edit this post to add the popups go ahead, or if you can leave me direction on how to do it .

Comment: Very disappointed that this was closed as an "exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic" thank you to the one who thought different.

Comment: What part of the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question?  That's how EVERY skill's damage is calculated.  1500% or 300%, the formula is the same, you just change a single value.

Comment: Can Trail of Cindersdo Crits?....Now with 1.05-Does anyone know if the any of the above change also (Weapon Damage vs DPS, Crit Chance)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand.  The only part of your question that *might* not be part of the duplicate is if ToC crits or not.  The rest is just part of the damage formula, which is the whole point of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using Trial of Cinders on my usual build because i think that 500% damage per second on a 1500% total for only 8 discipline is a steal. I also calculate some things cause i wanted to improve that knowing some more. So, Vault with trial of cinders doesn't take just your weapon damage but also your dex modifier and cannot crit in no way. I also notice that doesn't stack (but you also said that, i wanted only to see if it was as caltrops which doesn't stack the damage but stack the procs), I really don't know how this skill change in 1.05 because i didn't try PTR server, but i think that if they reduce the damage to 300%, it could crit aswell...If you take in consideration Rain of Vengeance, we can talk about 250% damage and it can crit, but don't take my opinion about new patch as sure.

Comment: The reason its being reduced to 300%, is because Blizzard intended that to be the damage over 5 secs (but accidentally made it tick that much per sec, leading to 1500% over 5s in 1.0.4). I doubt they will add in crit.

Comment: so it won't be reduced because it still do the same damage only in 5 sec instead of 3 right?

Comment: It _will_ be reduced - the damage it does in 1s now will be spread over 5s. Blizzard doesn't want discipline attacks to be better than hatred spenders.